# Elegant way of getting the Int value form Future[Option[Int]]

Tags: scala

Is there a more elegant way of getting the `Int` value from `Future[Option[Int]]` instead of using `finalFuture.value.get.get.get`?

This is what I have so far:

```
  val finalFuture: Future[Option[Int]] = result.contents

  finalFuture.onComplete {
              case Success(value) => println(s"Got the callback with value = ", finalFuture.value.get.get.get)
              case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could nest the match:

```
finalFuture.onComplete {
  case Success(Some(value)) => println(s"Got the callback with value = ", value)
  case Success(None) => ()
  case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` to apply a `A => Unit` function to the value in `Option[A]`, if it exists.

```
fut.onComplete {
  case Success(opt) => opt.foreach { val =>
    println(s"Got the callback with value = {}", val)
  }
  case Falure(ex) => ex.printStackTrace
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also the toOption of Try to get Option[Option[Int]] and then flatten to get Option[Int]

```
def printVal(finalFuture: Future[Option[Int]] ) =  finalFuture.onComplete( 
    _.toOption.flatten.foreach(x=> println (s"got {}",x))
  )
```

EDIT: That assuming you don't care about the stacktrace :)